# CloudFlare DNS SSL client certificate authentication

Tags: ssl, authentication, cloudflare

I have a Nginx server which is install client certificate authentication and works fine, here this the part which I write to configured SSL on Nginx.

```
server {
        listen   80;
        listen   443;
        ssl on;
        server_name ssl-api.mywebsite.com;

        ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/certs/verify-ssl-api-server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/certs/verify-ssl-api-server.key;
        ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/verify-ssl-api-rootCa.crt;
        ssl_verify_client on;
```

When I use the browser to access to this, an error message will show up like this picture.

[image]

And I add my client certificate to the Firefox and provide password to import clientcert.p12

[image]

A confirmation dialogue shows up, I've just need click OK and everything work fine.

[image]

Now I want to make this work on CLoudFlare's SSL but I don't know how. I've been trying [Authenticated Origin Pulls](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/204899617-Authenticated-Origin-Pulls) but it doesn't need to send client certificate, so how can I do this with CloudFlare?

Answer (score -1):

Try the following. On your listen 443 line you haven't said ssl, I don't know if it will do that by default or not. You shouldn't put http2 there unless your version of Nginx supports it.

```
listen 443 ssl http2;

ssl_certificate /var/lib/certs/fullchain;
ssl_certificate_key /var/lib/certs/privkey;

# Set up preferred protocols and ciphers. TLS1.2 is required for HTTP/2
# Change according to your needs
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

# This is a cache for SSL connections, it's optional but helps performance.
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:2m;
ssl_session_timeout 60m;
```

Get this working right in Chrome, Firefox, and IE. You may need to add intermediate certificates to get Firefox working, it's fussier. Once you do that CloudFlare should "just work".

Have a go and post your results, success or follow-up questions.